# How do I use a jaxb.index file?

Tags: jaxb

I'm getting

```
javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: "org.example.mypackage" doesnt contain ObjectFactory.class or jaxb.index
```

while trying to create a `JAXBContext` using `JAXBContext.newInstance(String contextPath)`.  I'm guessing there's a "usual" way to create and maintain a jaxb.index file.

Answer (score 38):

The jaxb.index file is just a listing of the classes in the containing package that have JAXB annotations.

Each line in the file is a class's simple name, not its fully qualified name.

You can read more here: http://cmaki.blogspot.com/2007/09/annotated-jaxb-classes.html

Comment: By classified, do you mean fully qualified class name? `Foo` would be class name and `com.a.b.c.Foo` would be fully qualified class name.

Answer (score 15):

Try this way,

```
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(new Class[] {your.package.Test.class});
```

Also, 
make sure that you added the `@XmlRootElement` to the Test class.

```
@XmlRootElement
class Test {
  private String ...;
  private int ......;
}
```

also make sure that you are using java 1.5

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you're passing the correct class to the method. Assuming your XML root element is XMLRoot, you would call it as:

```
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(XMLRoot.class);
```

Also make sure that you're using the correct version of the JAXB compiler (xjc) for the version of Java you're running. JAXB-generated classes from the old compiler won't work properly with Java 6's JAXB, giving the same error.

Comment: @Andrew Coleson - wouldn't you want to put the packagae name in there, not the root element tag name?