# UnmarshallingFailureException: JAXB unmarshalling exception; nested exception is javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException

Tags: java, spring, webservice-client

I am trying to send a SOAP request and receive the response by `WebServiceTemplate` but I am receiving following exception:

The WSDL is [here](http://ticketmaster.productserve.com/v2/soap.php?wsdl).

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [bb] in context with path [/Bb] threw 
exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is 
org.springframework.oxm.UnmarshallingFailureException: JAXB unmarshalling 
exception; nested exception is javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected 
element (uri:"http://ticketmaster.productserve.com/v2/soap.php", 
local:"findEventsResponse"). Expected elements are <{}findEvents>,<{}request>,
<{}sortTicket>] with root cause
```

**Request**

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlSeeAlso({Request.class})
public class FindEvents {
    @XmlElement
    private Request request;

           getter / setter
}


@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlSeeAlso({SortTicket.class})
public class Request {
    @XmlElement
    private String apiKey;
    @XmlElement
    private String country;
    @XmlElement
    private int resultsPerPage;
    @XmlElement
    private int currentPage;
    @XmlElement(name = "Sort")
    private SortTicket sort;
    @XmlElement
    private String[] filters;
    @XmlElement
    private String updatedSince;

           getters / setters
}

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class SortTicket {
    @XmlElement
    private String field;
    @XmlElement
    private String order;

           getters / setters
}
```

**Response**

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlSeeAlso({Return.class})
public class FindEventsResponse {
    @XmlElement
    private Return returnResult;

           getters / setters
}

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlSeeAlso({Details.class,Results.class})
public class Return {
    @XmlElement
    private Details details;
    @XmlElement
    private Results results;

           getters / setters
}

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Details {
    @XmlElement
    private int totalResults;
    @XmlElement
    private int totalPages;
    @XmlElement
    private int currentPage;
    @XmlElement
    private int resultsPerPage;

    getters / setters
}

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlSeeAlso({ Artist.class, Venue.class })
public class Results {
    @XmlElement
    private long eventId;
    @XmlElement
    private String ticketmasterEventId;
    @XmlElement
    private String status;
    @XmlElement
    private String name;
    @XmlElement
    private String url;
    @XmlElement
    private String eventDate;
    @XmlElement
    private String onSaleDate;
    @XmlElement
    private String preSaleDate;
    @XmlElement
    private int categoyId;
    @XmlElement
    private String parentCategory;
    @XmlElement
    private int parentCategoryId;
    @XmlElement
    private Double minPrice;
    @XmlElement
    private Double maxPrice;
    @XmlElement(name = "Artists")
    private Artist artist;
    @XmlElement
    private Venue venue;

     getters / setters
}


@XmlRootElement(name = "Artists")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Artist {
    @XmlElement
    private long artistId;
    @XmlElement
    private long ticketMasterArtistId;
    @XmlElement
    private String name;
    @XmlElement
    private String url;
    @XmlElement
    private String imageUrl;
    @XmlElement
    private String category;
    @XmlElement
    private int categoryId;
    @XmlElement
    private String parentCategory;
    @XmlElement
    private int parentCategoryId;

           getters / setters
}

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Venue {
    @XmlElement
    private long venueId;
    @XmlElement
    private long ticketmasterVenueId;
    @XmlElement
    private String name;
    @XmlElement
    private String street;
    @XmlElement
    private String city;
    @XmlElement
    private String country;
    @XmlElement
    private String postcode;
    @XmlElement
    private String url;
    @XmlElement
    private String imageUrl;
    @XmlElement
    private String state;

    getters / setters
}
```

Configuration is as follows

```
<oxm:jaxb2-marshaller id="marshaller">
        <oxm:class-to-be-bound name="com.bb.tickets.ticketmaster.FindEvents"/>
    </oxm:jaxb2-marshaller>

    <bean id="webServiceTemplate" 
        class="org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate">
        <property name="marshaller" ref="marshaller" />
        <property name="unmarshaller" ref="marshaller" />
        <property name="defaultUri"
            value="http://ticketmaster.productserve.com/v2/soap.php" />

    </bean>
```

The code to send the request and receive response

```
SortTicket sortTicket = new SortTicket();
Request request = new Request();
request.setApiKey("APIKEY");
request.setCountry("UK");
FindEvents findEvents = new FindEvents();
findEvents.setRequest(request);
FindEventsResponse response = (FindEventsResponse) 
webServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(findEvents);
System.err.println("response:"+ 
response.getReturnResult().getDetails().getCurrentPage());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the stack trace, I understand that JAX-B received a **findEventsResponse** of type `FindEventsResponse` to marshall but it expected a `FindEvents` object.

The issue lies within your spring configuration. You only told Spring that the `FindEvents` class should be bound to your marshaller. You need to add the `FindEventsResponse` class too, using the **classesToBeBound** property :

```
<oxm:jaxb2-marshaller id="marshaller">
    <property name="classesToBeBound">
        <list>
            <value>com.bb.tickets.ticketmaster.FindEvents</value>
            <value>com.bb.tickets.ticketmaster.FindEventsResponse</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</oxm:jaxb2-marshaller>
```

You could also bound a package using the **packageToScan** property, check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067703/specify-a-package-instead-of-classestobebound-for-spring-jaxb2marshaller).

Hope that does it.

[Edit]: if it doesn't work simply try :

```
<oxm:jaxb2-marshaller id="marshaller">
    <oxm:class-to-be-bound name="com.bb.tickets.ticketmaster.FindEvents"/>
    <oxm:class-to-be-bound name="com.bb.tickets.ticketmaster.FindEventsResponse"/>
</oxm:jaxb2-marshaller>
```

Comment: I used that but it returns following cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'property'. One of 
 '{"http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm":class-to-be-bound}' is expected.

Comment: I am using 4.1.5.RELEASE

Comment: That's strange, maybe there is an issue with you Spring config, check the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/oxm.html#oxm-jaxb2). My updated answer should work according to what I found in it.

Comment: I will, I just used the second option but it returns Failed to convert property value of type 'java.util.ArrayList' to required type 'java.lang.Class[]' for property 'classesToBeBound'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:

Comment: Do you have exactly the same pojos as those shown in you question? Where does that ArrayList come from ?